# How do I make Thunderbird behave like Gmail?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, tags

Specifically, things like the ability to give messages multiple tags and have them automatically show up in tag-folders.

When you use Gmail IMAP, it gives each tag a folder, and messages can appear in multiple folders.  I'd prefer something more like the real Gmail tag system.

Answer (score 1):

You can tag each email as you see fit. Then do 'Saved Search' folders to have them appear in said folder. This is in TB3 that is.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Tags are added with the Tag button at the top.

Comment: You can add as many tags as you would like to any message. Then if you do a search you can save as a 'search folder'.